# If $x^n$ is a zero-divisor, then $x$ is too.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. It is clear that if $x$ is a zero-divisor of $R$, then $x^n$ is also a zero-divisor for $n\ge1$. Why does the converse hold? In other words:

> if $x^n$ is a zero-divisor for $n\ge1$, why is $x$ also a zero-divisor?

Would you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know that if $xy$ is a zero-divisor, then either $x$ or $y$ is a zero-divisor?

Comment: Well, it's simply associativity $$0=x^n \cdot y = x \cdot (x^{n-1}y)$$

Comment: @Crostul how do you know $x^{n-1}y$ is non-zero?

Comment: @quid He didn't claim so. But ... induction.

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou it says " it's simply associativity" which to me suggests this is supposed to be an essentially complete argument, which it is not.

Comment: @EricWofsey If $xy$ is a zero divisor, then there exists an element $z\neq0$ such that $\left(xy\right)z=0$ and so $x\left(yz\right)=0$. How do we know that $yz$ or $xz$ is distinct form zero?

Comment: @User1999: We don't, but what happens if they are zero?

Comment: @User1999 IF $yz=0$, then $y$ is a zero divisor. If $xz=0$, then $x$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: @EricWofsey@SahibaArora Thank you very much! Now I can see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $y \neq 0$ such that $x^ny=0$. Then $x(x^{n-1}y)=0$, so either $x$ is a zero divisor or $x^{n-1}y=0$, that is $x^{n-1}$ is a zero divisor. Then descending induction on $n$ completes the proof.